# Does SQL Server support join type "LEFT SEMI JOIN" in your query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

While I was watching [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcyhh_fjsc4), I found the author seems using SSMS.
[image]

I never know SQL Server supports the `LEFT SEMI JOIN` syntax, so I give it a try with the following code.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.emp,
                     dbo.dept;
CREATE TABLE emp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(20), age INT, deptid INT);
CREATE TABLE dept (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(20));
GO

INSERT INTO dept (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Dept 1');
INSERT INTO dept (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Dept 2');
INSERT INTO dept (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Dept 3');
INSERT INTO dept (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Dept 4');

INSERT INTO emp (id, name, age, deptid) VALUES (1, 'Emp 01 Dept 4', 30, 4);
INSERT INTO emp (id, name, age, deptid) VALUES (2, 'Emp 02 Dept 1', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO emp (id, name, age, deptid) VALUES (3, 'Emp 03 Dept 2', 18, 2);
INSERT INTO emp (id, name, age, deptid) VALUES (4, 'Emp 04 Dept 4', 32, 4);
INSERT INTO emp (id, name, age, deptid) VALUES (5, 'Emp 05 Dept 5', 32, 5);
GO

SELECT * FROM emp e LEFT SEMI JOIN dept d ON e.deptid = d.id;
```

However, when I run it, I got this error:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
> 'SEMI' is not a recognized join option.

Does SQL Server support this "LEFT SEMI JOIN" syntax in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Row Goals, Part 2: Semi Joins](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/row-goals-part-2-semi-joins) by Paul White

> T-SQL currently lacks support for direct syntax like FROM A SEMI JOIN
> B ON A.x = B.y, so we need to use indirect forms like EXISTS, SOME/ANY
> (including the equivalent shorthand IN for equality comparisons), and
> set INTERSECT.

In [this](https://sqlity.net/en/1348/a-join-a-day-the-left-semi-join/#:%7E:text=Summary,might%20not%20always%20use%20it.) article by sqlity.net, there are examples about how to achieve a `left semi join` using tsql.

Comment: I also mention in [part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) of that series that U-SQL does support that syntax (though U-SQL is now deprecated). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/semijoin